# Can't disable dark mode in android below 29

Tags: java, android, darkmode

I'm new to android, creating an android app for marshmallow to current version users, In my app I try to disable `dark mode` but it is not working for me.

```
AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode(AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_NO);

<style name="Theme.MyApp" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.DarkActionBar">
```

```
getDelegate().setLocalNightMode(AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_NO);
```

```
 <item name="android:forceDarkAllowed" tools:targetApi="q">false</item>
```

I tried this methods but it is not worked for me. How can I achieve this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest way to disable `Dark Mode` is

```
android:forceDarkAllowed="false"
```

in your `main_activity.xml`  root `Layout` also,

```
Override Resource in layout-v29
```